# Let $n\geq 2$ be a positive integer. If $p$ is a prime that divides ${2n \choose n}$, prove that $p < 2n$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, binomial-coefficients

I don't think this  proof ought to be too difficult, but I'm finding myself stuck. I know that $p \vert \frac{(2n)(2n-1)...(n+1)}{n!}$, and thus that $p \vert (2n)(2n-1)...(n+1)$. But what does that indicate about the bounds on $p$?

After some further research, it looks like I'm trying to prove the inverse of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2103981/show-that-if-p-is-a-prime-satisfying-np2n-then-binom2nn-equiv-0-mod).

Anyway, any hints or nudges in the right direction would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know Euclid's lemma?

Comment: Didn't know of it until now, but I see that it's what I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numerator of the expression for ${2n \choose n}$ is a product of integers each $< 2n$.  Any prime that divides ${2n \choose n}$ must divide at least one of those...